# android ndk Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

when I build ndk app, an error occures:

```
Error:(21, 10) fatal error: 'asm/types.h' file not found
```

I have found an answer from a similar questions, that adds to `CMakeLists.txt`

```
if(${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi)
elseif(${ANDROID_ABI} STREQUAL "arm64-v8a")
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android)
else()
    include_directories(${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi)
endif()
```

But another error occures:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process D:\Android\sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\AndroidStudioProjects\camerandk\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\arm64-v8a --target native-camera2-lib}
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-camera2-lib.dir/native-camera2-lib.cpp.o
  [2/2] Linking CXX shared library D:\AndroidStudioProjects\camerandk\app\src\main\jniLibs\arm64-v8a\libnative-camera2-lib.so
  FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=D:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=D:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -Wno-error=format-security -Wno-error=pointer-sign -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a --sysroot D:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libnative-camera2-lib.so -o D:\AndroidStudioProjects\camerandk\app\src\main\jniLibs\arm64-v8a\libnative-camera2-lib.so CMakeFiles/native-camera2-lib.dir/native-camera2-lib.cpp.o  -landroid -lcamera2ndk -llog -latomic -lm "D:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_static.a" && cd ."
  D:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lcamera2ndk
  clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
```

Comment: The error message is `cannot find -lcamera2ndk`. Do you have camera2ndk package installed?

Comment: thank you very much. minSdkVersion  don't support camera2ndk.I try    A higher to    .